# Prevent Gmail from saving sent mail

Tags: gmail

I have created a Gmail account to be used for sending scans from my network printer.

Gmail obviously saves sent mail automatically as it should, but in this particular case, I would prefer this not being done to avoid the sent mail being quickly filled with emails containing relatively large attachments that have been already sent to the intended recipient.

Is there a way to either:

1. Automatically periodically delete sent mail, say older that 30 days (preferred).
2. Configure Gmail not to save sent messages.
3. Keep messages, but delete attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a third-party mail reader such as [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/), with add-on [Xpunge].

*Xpunge* can be set to clear any number of folders, and can be set to do so on a timer. This tool can work on multiple accounts, whether GMail or other mail services.

Answer (score 1):

On your own risk, try to create following Filter in Gmail Settings. It may delete all newly sent mail: add "in:sent" (without quotation marks) in field for matching words and set action Delete.

My another attempt was clicking search field and setting From: you@gmail.com (in case you are sending e-mail from multiple aliases, you can use: you@gmail.com OR you@otherdomain.com)
search in: Sent
action: delete

Comment: Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail

Answer (score 0):

Number one would probably require a custom written GApps script to perform those tasks. Definitely possible and probably relatively easy if you have coded with javascript before.

<s>Number two: You can setup a filter in GMail to automatically tag everything with a sent tag with a trash tag as well. That would also keep the messages for a few days (I think 30 by default) in the trash folder.</s>

Number three: I'm not aware of anything that could do this.

Edit: GMail filters only work on incoming mail. The answer has been updated to reflect that.

Comment: Filters in Gmail only work on incoming mail.